# For a Community Wiki Question, Should I Accept an Answer?

Tags: support, community-wiki

(I've searched Meta for a related question, but didn't find anything.)

[The first Question I asked on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13539/what-are-security-best-practices-for-wordpress-plugins-and-themes) was intended from the start to be a Community Wiki (which I am assuming means "collection of resources, for which there may be no single, correct answer").

My question is: should I accept an answer for this question? It continues to show up in my profile, and WPSE nags me about accepting an answer; also, I want to ensure that my accept rate remains appropriate.

Sorry if this is a dumb/obvious question; I'm still learning the nuances of WPSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is on the wiki it doesn't effect your acceptance rate so there is no need to accept an answer. Although yes you get that nag screen. I think if its on the wiki the nag screen shouldn't show.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know; thanks!

Comment: Also: is there anything we can do to get Community Wiki questions removed from the Profile nag section?

Answer (score 2):

I think that community wiki posts do not influence accept rate. Well, I've seen mentions of that, so it may or may not be how things currently work.

I tend to accept some answer I particularly like or agree with, but that doesn't carry much weight or meaning in community wiki anyway.